# Installing printer samsung ml-1860 with xubuntu 14.04?

Tags: drivers, printing, samsung

Having problem with installing printer samsung ml-1860 wiht xubuntu 14.04.
rastertosplc file missing in cups/filter directory.

Comment: See http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ for instructions on installing samsung printers.

Comment: @Rinzwind The site you have quoted states, that the solution is for Intel only.

Comment: And what do you believe that means? :)  (and NO the answer is -not- the -company- intel and amd.

Answer (score 3):

I have this same printer model and I am using Ubuntu 14.04.  I downloaded the same driver from Samsung and got the same error.  I read on a different forum that the Samsung driver has an error on it.  I was instructed to download the driver for the ml-1860w which is basically the same printer but with added wifi printing functions.  I did and my printer works perfectly now.

http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/model/ML-1865W/XAA-downloads#

I downloaded the driver.

I used the commands: cd ~/Downloads/uld

And then: sudo sh install.sh

(your download might be in a different location)

Comment: the current link is https://support.hp.com/ca-en/drivers/selfservice/closure/samsung-ml-1860-laser-printer-series/19134650 but the driver fails.

Answer (score 2):

After you've done what user282227 said, you'll need to install the printer. I've tried his steps and that only seems to installed the drivers in the system folder, but it won't install the printer for using it right away.

Sorry if I don't express myself correctly, this is my first comment (new for Ubuntu, or even Unix).

After that, go to
-System settings
-Printer
-Add
-Open the 'Network Printer' menu
-Select the printer
-Select 'IPP' connection type to your right, hit Forward
-Won't need to RE install the drivers, so it'll ask you for a name for your printer, hit Forward
-Done

I've printed a 'Test Page' right after all that and it did work through WiFi connection. Haven tried through USB connection.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to follow the installation of SAMSUNG ML-1860 printer

1. Go to: http://www.samsung.com/latin/support/model/ML-1860/XAX and
   download the driver `uld_v1.00.36_00.91.tar.gz`.
2. To work better, copy the downloaded file to the Desktop
3. Open the console and locate on the desktop where the file with the
   extension `.tar.gz` is already supposed to be.
4. type: `tar -zxvf uld_v1.00.36_00.91.tar.gz` without the quotation
   marks and press Enter. This command will generate a folder with the name `uld`
5. List item

Change to the `uld` folder by typing `cd uld` and enter. Then type `sudo sh install.sh` and follow the Enter prompts to continue and to accept, `N` to skip the firewall. That's it.

Then follow the recommendations of "ntried".